# Tengo una duda... ¿Por qué me da este error si tengo instalado el fensorflow?

Tags: inteligencia-artificial

[image: Estoy empezando a estudiar Deep Learning con python y me salio ese error queriendo correr el progra]

Estoy empezando a estudiar Deep Learning con python y me salio ese error queriendo correr el programa, solo que tengo instalado perfectamente el tensorflow...

Comment: Probablemente no estás ejecutando tu programa con la versión de python en la que instalaste la librería de tensorflow.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? ¡No todos pueden ver las imágenes! Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! Encontré tu duda en el blog general. Espero que te ayude

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568913/tensorflow-import-error-no-module-named-tensorflow

Comment: ¡[so] no es un blog! (aunque tiene su [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog) aparte, que ese es otro tema). Además, debes incluir el contenido esencial del enlace aquí. Piénsalo: si el enlace llega a romperse, parte fundamental de la respuesta se perderá, invalidando la respuesta. La respuesta debe ser útil no solo para quien redactó la pregunta, sino también para los demás usuarios más adelante. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).